# How to pass self to function instance when it gets assigned in a decorator?

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

I am trying to assign dictionary keys to object functions but for some reason it won't work inside of decorators.  When I try to call a.run(), self doesn't seem to be passed into the dictionary func.  I also don't have access to f.**self** in decorator so I know it has to be something wrong in there.  I have written a simple example of my code.  I want it to be something similar to app.route in flask being that it init the mapping between endpoints and functions.

ERROR:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 27, in <module>
    a.run()
  File "main.py", line 14, in run
    self.rmap[k](data)
TypeError: one_way() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'
```

CODE:

```
class A (object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.rmap = {}

  def route(self, r):
    def decorator(f):
      self.rmap[r] = f
      return f
    return decorator

  def run(self):
    data = [1,2,3]
    for k in self.rmap.keys():
      self.rmap[k](data)

a = A()

class B (object):
  def __init__(self):
    pass


  @a.route('/one/way')
  def one_way (self, data):
    print('A WAY:{}'.format(self))

b = B()
a.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time it's being decorated, [`one_way()` is a plain function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod), not a method - it only becomes a method when looked up on a `B` instance. IOW, you need to explicitely provide a `B` instance when calling it from `A().run()` (the fact you have a global `b` instance in your code is irrelevant - the function object stored in `a.rmap` knows absolutely nothing about it, nor even about the `B` class FWIW.

To make a long story short, your current design cannot work as is. If you only ever intend to decorate methods (well, functions) from one single class and call them on one single instance of this class, you could pass an instance of this class to `a.run()` ie:

```
class A():
   # ...
   def run(self, obj):
    data = [1,2,3]
    for k in self.rmap.keys():
        self.rmap[k](obj, data)

b = B()
a.run(b)
```

but this would be of very limited use.

Or you could just use the decorator to "mark" functions to be used for routing (together with the effective route), add some `register()` methdo to `A` and explicitely pass `B` or whatever else instance to this method ie

```
 def route(r):
    def decorator(f):
        f._A_route = r
        return f
    return decorator


class A (object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rmap = {}

    def register(self, *objects):
        for obj in objects:
            self._register(obj)

    def _register(self, obj):
        for name in dir(obj):
            if name.startswith("_"):
                continue
            attr = getattr(obj, name)
            if callable(attr) and hasattr(attr, "_A_route"):
                self.rmap[attr._A_route] = attr

    def run(self):
        data = [1,2,3]
        for k in self.rmap.keys():
            self.rmap[k](data)

class B (object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass


    @route('/one/way')
    def one_way (self, data):
        print('A WAY:{}'.format(self))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A()
    b = B()
    a.register(b)
    a.run()
```

Now there might be better solutions for your concrete use case, but it's impossible to tell without knowing about the whole context etc.

Comment: ok thank you for your detailed answer.  I will probably go with some variation of the the second method because I also want it to work if it's also just a plain function.

Answer (score 1):

When calling `self.rmap[k](data)` you are not passing in the `self` parameter. This has to be an instance of class `B` in order to work.

Normally you'd just pass on the parameters with which the decorated function was called, but you seem to want to use your decorated function differently. In your case what would work is:

```
def run(self):
    data = [1,2,3]
    b = B()
    for k in self.rmap.keys():
        self.rmap[k](b, data)
```

You could of course also instantiate the `B` instance somewhere else if you want to reuse it between calls.